# Don't Display Date if Same as Previous Entry

Tags: swiftui, ios14

I have a list of entries each with an attached date. I would like to display the date only if there is a change in date. I first developed this software in iOS 14.4 that resulted in a view immutable error. This was because I was storing and changing a copy of the entry date.

Now in version iOS 14.5 I don't see the immutable error. But my software still doesn't work. If you run the code and look in the console you will note that Xcode is going through my six entries twice: the first time is always true (show the date) and the second time always false (don't show the date). Why?

In my actual code I am using dates of type Date instead of Strings in this example code. In my actual code, operation hangs as it loops endlessly through my function checkDate (Many times more than the number of entries). Does date of type Date include the time causing the compare to fail?

Is there a better way to prevent display of the date if it is the same as the previous entry?

```
struct KitchenItem:  Codable, Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    var item: String
    var itemDate: String
    var itemCost: Double
}

class Pantry: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var oldDate: String = ""
    @Published var kitchenItem: [KitchenItem]
    
    init() {
        self.kitchenItem = []
        
        let item0 = KitchenItem(item: "String Beans", itemDate: "1/13/2021", itemCost: 4.85)
        self.kitchenItem.append(item0)
        
        let item1 = KitchenItem(item: "Tomatoes", itemDate: "1/22/2021", itemCost: 5.39)
        self.kitchenItem.append(item1)
        
        let item2 = KitchenItem(item: "Bread", itemDate: "1/22/2021", itemCost: 4.35)
        self.kitchenItem.append(item2)
        
        let item3 = KitchenItem(item: "Corn", itemDate: "3/18/2021", itemCost: 2.75)
        self.kitchenItem.append(item3)
        
        let item4 = KitchenItem(item: "Peas", itemDate: "3/18/2021", itemCost: 7.65)
        self.kitchenItem.append(item4)
        
        let item5 = KitchenItem(item: "Ice Cream", itemDate: "4/12/2021", itemCost: 7.95)
        self.kitchenItem.append(item5)
    }
}


struct ContentView: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var pantry: Pantry = Pantry()
    
    var body: some View {
        
        LazyVStack (alignment: .leading) {
            Text("Grandma's Food Pantry")
                .font(.title)
                .fontWeight(.bold)
                .padding(.top, 36)
                .padding(.leading, 36)
                .padding(.bottom, 30)
            
            ForEach(0..<pantry.kitchenItem.count, id: \.self) { item in
                
                VStack (alignment: .leading) {
                    showRow(item: item)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


struct showRow: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var pantry: Pantry = Pantry()
    
    var item: Int
    
    var body: some View {
        
        // don't show the date if is the same as the previous entry
        let newDate = pantry.kitchenItem[item].itemDate
        if checkDate(newDate: newDate) == true {
            Text("\n\(newDate)")
                .font(.title2)
                .padding(.leading, 10)
        }
        
        HStack {
            Text("\(pantry.kitchenItem[item].item)")
                .padding(.leading, 50)
                .frame(width: 150, alignment: .leading)
            
            Text("\(pantry.kitchenItem[item].itemCost, specifier: "$%.2f")")
        }
    }
    
    func checkDate(newDate: String) -> (Bool) {
        print("    ")
        print("new date = \(newDate)")
       
        if newDate == pantry.oldDate {
            print("false: don't show the date")
            return false
        } else {
            pantry.oldDate = newDate
            print("old date = \(pantry.oldDate)")
            print("true: show the date")
            return true
        }
    }
}
```

**Actual code:**

```
struct ListView: View {
    
    @EnvironmentObject var categories: Categories
    @EnvironmentObject var userData: UserData
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var viewContext
    
    var money: String = ""
    var xchRate: Double = 0.0
    var cat: Int = 0
    var mny: String = ""
    
    @FetchRequest(
        entity: CurrTrans.entity(),
        sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \CurrTrans.entryDT, ascending: true)]
    ) var currTrans: FetchedResults<CurrTrans>
    
    var body: some View {
        
        GeometryReader { g in
            ScrollView {
                LazyVStack (alignment: .leading) {
                    
                    TitleView()
                    
                    ForEach(currTrans, id: \.self) { item in
                            showRow(item: item, priorDate: priorDate(forItemIndex: item), g: g)
                    }
                    .onDelete(perform: deleteItem)
                }
                .font(.body)
            }
        }
    }
    
    private func priorDate(forItemIndex item: Int) -> Date? {
           guard item > 0 else { return nil }
           return currTrans[item - 1].entryDT
       }
}
struct showRow: View {
    
    @EnvironmentObject var userData: UserData
    
    var item: CurrTrans
    var priorDate: Date?
    var g: GeometryProxy
    
    var payType = ["Cash/Debit", "Credit"]
    
    var body: some View {
        
        // don't show the date if is the same as the previous entry
        let gotDate = item.entryDT ?? Date()
        let newDate = gotDate.getFormattedDate()
            Text("\(newDate)")
                .opacity(gotDate == priorDate ? 0 : 1)
                .font(.title2)
                .padding(.leading, 10)
     
          displays entry parameters in HStack...
```

Comment: Unrelated but be aware that the `pantry` objects in `ContentView` and `showRow` are two different instances. You should create the `ObservableObject` only once and pass it down the hierarchy.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that I have more than one instance of my class Pantry. It looks like my example code has gone off in the weeds!  I’m a longtime firmware engineer working in C and assembly where we don’t have to worry about classes and instances. My actual code does pass it down via the hierarchy and the entries are stored in coredata. Here is the fetch:

@FetchRequest(
 Entity: CurrTrans.entity(),
 sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keypath: \CurrTrans.entryDT, ascending: true)]
var currTrans: FetchedResults<CurrTrans>

Answer (score 0):

### Thou shalt not mutate thy data inside thy `body` method, for it is an abomination in the eyes of SwiftUI.

Modifying `oldDate` inside the `body` method is wrong. SwiftUI will get confused if you modify the data it is observing while it is rendering your views. Furthermore, SwiftUI doesn't make any guarantees about the order in which it renders the children of a `LazyVStack` (or any other container).

> Is there a better way to prevent display of the date if it is the same as the previous entry?

Yes. Pass the current entry, and the prior entry's date, to the entry view.

Here's your data model and store, without the cruft:

```
struct KitchenItem:  Codable, Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    var item: String
    var itemDate: String
    var itemCost: Double
}

class Pantry: ObservableObject {
    @Published var kitchenItems: [KitchenItem] = [
        .init(item: "String Beans", itemDate: "1/13/2021", itemCost: 4.85),
        .init(item: "Tomatoes", itemDate: "1/22/2021", itemCost: 5.39),
        .init(item: "Bread", itemDate: "1/22/2021", itemCost: 4.35),
        .init(item: "Corn", itemDate: "3/18/2021", itemCost: 2.75),
        .init(item: "Peas", itemDate: "3/18/2021", itemCost: 7.65),
        .init(item: "Ice Cream", itemDate: "4/12/2021", itemCost: 7.95),
    ]
}
```

For each `KitchenItem`, you need to also extract the prior item's date, if there is a prior item. We'll use a helper method, `priorDate(forItemIndex:)`, to do that. Also, you need to use `StateObject`, not `ObservedObject`, if you're going to create your store inside the view. Thus:

```
struct ContentView: View {

    @StateObject var pantry: Pantry = Pantry()

    var body: some View {
        ScrollView(.vertical) {
            LazyVStack (alignment: .leading) {
                Text("Grandma's Food Pantry")
                    .font(.title)
                    .fontWeight(.bold)
                    .padding(.top, 36)
                    .padding(.leading, 36)
                    .padding(.bottom, 30)

                ForEach(0 ..< pantry.kitchenItems.count) { i in
                    if i > 0 {
                        Divider()
                    }
                    KitchenItemRow(item: pantry.kitchenItems[i], priorDate: priorDate(forItemIndex: i))
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private func priorDate(forItemIndex i: Int) -> String? {
        guard i > 0 else { return nil }
        return pantry.kitchenItems[i - 1].itemDate
    }
}
```

Here is `KitchenItemRow`. You can see that it makes the date `Text` transparent if the date is the same as the prior item's date. I keep it in place but make it transparent so the row lays out the same:

```
struct KitchenItemRow: View {
    var item: KitchenItem
    var priorDate: String?

    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            HStack {
                Text(item.item)
                Spacer()
                Text("\(item.itemCost, specifier: "$%.2f")")
            }
            Text(item.itemDate)
                .opacity(item.itemDate == priorDate ? 0 : 1)
        }
        .padding([.leading, .trailing], 10)
    }
}
```

And here is `TitleView`, extracted from `ContentView` for hygiene:

```
struct TitleView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Grandma's Food Pantry")
            .font(.title)
            .fontWeight(.bold)
            .padding(.top, 36)
            .padding(.leading, 36)
            .padding(.bottom, 30)

    }
}
```

Result:

[image: screen shot of iPhone 12 Mini simulator showing the kitchen item list with duplicate dates suppressed]

### UPDATE

Since your “real code” uses `onDelete`, it's important to give `ForEach` an id for each item instead of using the indexes.

Note that [`onDelete` only works inside `List`, not inside `LazyVStack`](https://www.google.com/search?q=lazyvstack+ondelete&oq=lazyvstack+ondelete&aqs=chrome.0.0j69i57.2471j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8).

So we need to map each item to its index, so we can find the prior item. Here's a revised version of my `ContentView` that uses `onDelete`:

```
struct ContentView: View {

    @StateObject var pantry: Pantry = Pantry()

    var body: some View {
        let indexForItem: [UUID: Int] = .init(
            uniqueKeysWithValues: pantry.kitchenItems.indices.map {
                (pantry.kitchenItems[$0].id, $0) })

        List {
            TitleView()

            ForEach(pantry.kitchenItems, id: \.id) { item in
                let i = indexForItem[item.id]!
                KitchenItemRow(item: item, priorDate: priorDate(forItemIndex: i))
            }
            .onDelete(perform: deleteItems(at:))
        }
    }

    private func priorDate(forItemIndex i: Int) -> String? {
        guard i > 0 else { return nil }
        return pantry.kitchenItems[i - 1].itemDate
    }

    private func deleteItems(at offsets: IndexSet) {
        pantry.kitchenItems.remove(atOffsets: offsets)
    }
}
```

In my testing, this works and allows swipe-to-delete. I trust you can adapt it to your “real” code.

Comment: Hi Rob: 
I have included my actual code above.  I am not sure how to implement the priorDate private function with a return type Date? which I need to support by my coredata date type